# Use Python/urllib to access web sites with "siteminder" authentication?

Tags: python, url, web, siteminder

I am trying to access and parse  a website at work using Python. The sites authorization is done via siteminder, so the usual urllib/urllib2 user password does not work.
Does anyone have an idea how to do that?
Thanks
NoamM

Answer (score 2):

Just did this - I know its an oldie - but if anyone else looking to do this - use the requests library. I had done this in C# before and used mammoth amounts of code - but this is all it takes to login to my corporate siteminder system - nice. The request.session() object will persist redirects, headers and cookies - so all you need to worry about is posting the login form. I'm sure the variables will be different in your environment, but the process will be the same.

output.text will be the body of the target page you wanted to parse which you can then xpath or whatever.

```
import requests
r = requests.session()
postUrl = "https://loginUrl"
params = {  'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
            'SMENC': 'ISO-8859-1',
            'SMLOCALE': 'US-EN',
            'target': '/redir.shtml?GOTO=redirecturl}',
            'smauthreason': '0' }

r.post(postUrl, data=params)

getUrl = "http://urlFromBehindLogInYouWantDataFrom"
output = r.get(getUrl)
print(output.text)
```

Comment: don't forget `pip install requests`

Also, you don't have to do the extra get when provided the correct redirect or target url that most authentications have.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should find out what's happening when you authenticate through siteminder. Perhaps there's documentation for it, but if not it's not so hard to find out: the Network tab in Chrome or Safari's developer tools has all the information you need: HTTP Headers and Cookies for every network request. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can give you that as well.

Once you have a clear idea of what's happening at each step of the authentication process, it's only a matter of replicating the same behavior in your script. [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) has support for [cookies](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar) and [headers](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.add_header). If you need something urllib2 doesn't provide, [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) will probably do.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Martin - you need to just replicate what the browser does. Siteminder will pass you a token once successfully authenticated. I have to do this as well, will post once I find a good way.

Comment: Have you ever gotten around to do that?